# Wiremock.net (C#) how to get a PDF from a Request body (form-data )

Tags: wiremock, wiremock.net

We are using wiremock.net (C#) and we want to extract from the request the PDF file contained in that Request. How can we do that? I'm new to wiremock and I read about response templating without success.

Can someone please help with either documentation or code sample for this?

In other words how to GET_PDF FILE_HERE_FROM_REQUEST (see code below)

[image]

```
wireMockServer
            .Given(Request.Create().WithPath("/validatePDFA").UsingPost())
            .RespondWith(Response.Create()
                .WithStatusCode(200)
                .WithHeader("Content-Type", "form-data")
                .WithBody(req => ReadFileAndGenerateJsonBody(GET_PDF FILE_HERE_FROM_REQUEST))                    
            );

 public string ReadFileAndGenerateJsonBody(...)
{
     //read text from PDF  file 
     //build jsonResponse
     return jsonResponse
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please refer to the [answer by](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/issues/1067) a great guy (he must be!) @stefH

Here is the full text =>

In your example you are posting a form which has 2 fields: a file field, which contains the PDF and a json text field.

If you want to return a JSON response, you need to use the method (which gives you the request object and should return an anonymous object which will be serialized to JSON:

```
IResponseBuilder WithBodyAsJson(Func<IRequestMessage, Task<object>> bodyFactory, Encoding? encoding = null);
```

And the `IRequestMessage` contains a property `BodyAsMimeMessage` which is an `MimeKit.MimeMessage` object which contains several body parts which you can get and use if needed.
Example:

```
foreach (var mimePart in message.BodyParts.OfType<MimeKit.MimePart>())
{
// ...
}
```

See https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit for more details